# Laravel5.5: migration string to JSON

Tags: json, laravel, migration

How to make a migration in Laravel 5.5 that change the datatype of a String to JSON? My column has image links and I want to change it to JSON to store more links.

I thought this was the best way?

- change the string value of the column so it corresponds to JSON datatype
- change the datatype of the column to JSON

I'm able to do the first step in mysql by:

```
UPDATE db.vendor_horses SET image= CONCAT('{"images":["', image, '"]}');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a new migration with `php artisan make:migration migration_name` command.

Use the following to change the datatype

```
Schema::table('vendor_horses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->json('image')->change();
});
```

The change() method allows you to set nullable, modify data length and types. Read more about [change()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#modifying-columns)

Comment: Does the change command changes the value? Because now the value of the column is just "img/image01.jpg". Not a valid json string

Comment: Also remember to take a data backup before running anything on production.

Comment: Nope, change command won't change the value. I thought you had already done that using the sql command.

Comment: Also you wouldn't want to change values in a migration anyways.

Comment: Migration should just change the schema of your db, I feel. not that you can't do it. But I would prefer making a seeder or just run a query directly to change the current content, **if it's one time**

Comment: I thought doing it like this?:
        DB::statement('UPDATE db.vendor_horses SET image= CONCAT('{"images":["', image, '"]}');');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189934/discussion-between-bharat-geleda-and-belgiums).

Answer (score 0):

this just supported mySql version 8 to up

```
Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) { 
$table->json('field_name')->change(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, If you use laravel and change your database table field then you install `composer require doctrine/dbal` Read more about [modifying a column](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns) in laravel

Simply create a new migration file from `php artisan make:migration migration_name` and then open newly created migration file

```
Schema::table('your_table_name',function(Blueprint $table){

 $table->json('image')->change();

 //make nullable to image field 
 $table->json('image')->nullable()->change();

 //rename image field to other 
  $table->renameColumn('old_column_name', 'new_column_name');

})
```

The change() method allow you to set data length , change your column name, and make nullable

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8mb4_

Comment: this is a example of db column value:
{"images":["/vendors/57/horse-11.png"]}

Comment: please check your mysql version gretter or equal 5.7 then you use the JSON data type